# Why is repository null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm making an API and I'm making API calls.
I created an repository named `IPartnerRepository`
When I run my call It gives the nullexception error.
When I debug my code I see that `IPartnerRepository` is null.
My visual studio doesn't show any errors or mistypings.
Why can't my program find that repository then? Why is it null?

This is my code:

```
public IPartnerRepository PartnerRepository { get; set; } // = null

[RequiresAnyRole(Roles.superadmin, Roles.admin)]
public async Task<PartnerListResponse> Get(PartnerListRequest request)
{
   var items = await PartnerRepository.GetAllAsync();
   return new PartnerListResponse
   {
      Items = items
   };
}
```

**IPartnerRepository**

```
using System;
using DTO = Ringdesk.Api.ServiceModel.DTO;

namespace Ringdesk.Api.ServiceModel.Interfaces
{
   public interface IPartnerRepository : IDtoRepository<DTO.Partner, 
      DTO.PartnerForInsert, DTO.PartnerForUpdate>
   {
   }
}
```

**Partner.cs**

```
using ServiceStack.Model;
using Ringdesk.Api.ServiceModel.Attributes;

namespace Ringdesk.Api.ServiceModel.DTO
{
    public class Partner : IHasId<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        [PropertyValue("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PartnerForUpdate : IHasId<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PartnerForInsert
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

[image: the working code with customers]

[image: the partners code that goes wrong]

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ServiceStack;
using Ringdesk.Api.Web.Jobs;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Web;

namespace Ringdesk.Api.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOrchardCms();
            //services.AddMvc();
        }

        public class StartupSettings
        {
            public bool RunJobs { get; set; }
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {
            var startupSettings = Configuration.GetSection("startupSettings").Get<StartupSettings>();

            if (startupSettings == null || startupSettings.RunJobs)
            {
                var quartz = new QuartzSetup();
                lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(quartz.Start);
                lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(quartz.Stop);
            }

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            var appSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration);
            app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost(appSettings));
            app.UseOrchardCore();

            //app.UseMvc(routes =>
            //      {
            //        routes.MapRoute(
            //            name: "default",
            //            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //      });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `public IPartnerRepository PartnerRepository { get; set; }` that's why it's `NULL`

Comment: Well, where do you believe you're setting the `PartnerRepository` property to a non-null value? I don't see that anywhere in the code you've provided so far. If you're expecting a dependency injection framework to do that for you, please provide details about how you've set that up.

Comment: This will not happen magically. You have to provide a value by yourself. You can see the `{get; set;}` methods like getter and setter methods in other languages. C# just makes it easier for you by providing the default implementation of a getter and setter method (Properties are explained in details [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-properties-in-C-Sharp/)).

Comment: There has to be a difference. Are you using a dependency injection framework? If so did you forget to register an instance for `IPartnerRepository`?

Comment: I'd suggest you `Find All References` on `CustomerRepository` - the **class**, not the field. Does anything look like a IoC / DI registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the PartnerRepository to the servicemodule I fixed it!

```
container.RegisterAs<PartnerRepository, IPartnerRepository>();
container.Register<IDtoRepository<Db.PartnerProperty, Db.PartnerProperty, Db.PartnerProperty>>(c =>
{
   var repository = new DtoRepository<Db.PartnerProperty, Db.PartnerProperty, Db.PartnerProperty, Db.PartnerProperty>();
   c.AutoWire(repository);
   return repository;
});
```

This already existed for `CustomerRepository`

Like @Croxy said I forgot to assign a value to the `CustomerRepository` inside the `ServiceModule`

Answer (score -1):

This is Runtime Error, which is caused by Logical Error. Visual Studio complains about Compiler Errors.

There are some tools like ReSharper which gives developer friendly feedbacks for the developers while coding such that `variable may be null` however you cannot expect from Visual Studio or from any other Development Environment/Tool to always find and give you suggestions about Logical errors/Runtime errors.

In your case this problem is arisen because you declared `public IPartnerRepository PartnerRepository { get; set; }` but never set it to an instance.

The instantiation can be done in multiple ways, but simplest and common way is constructor initialization

```
class Something
{
     Something()
     {
          PartnerRepository = new PartnerRepository(....);
     }

     // then your methods here
}
```